# REST API - Add item as relational resource to another resource

Tags: rest, http, relationship

I have been wondering what would be the best approach when adding a resource that is linked to another resource.

I have two objects:
+ Employee: An employee for an IT company
+ Skill: The employee set of technology skills; for example, Java.

Someone can create an employee via REST with the following path:
`POST: /employee`

Though someone could create a `Skill` object by itself, similar to creating an `Employee` object, but it needs to be linked to an `Employee`, thus...

`PATCH: /employee/{employeeId}/skill`

This path will create a new `Skill` to the `Employee` object, but this is where I am wondering if I am doing something wrong.

Usually when you create a new resource, you use the `POST` verb, but at the same time I am also updating part of the `Employee` resource thus it acts like a `PATCH` verb. Plus, a `POST` verb should be free from any parameters like `{employeeId}`.

What would be the best approach / practice when documenting REST API with this scenario?

Comment: `POST` is defined to process a payload according to its own semantics. It may create a new resource, in which case it should create a `Location` header to indicate a resource creation, but it does not have to. If you design skills to be their own resource, than use `POST` for it. If you consider skills to be some subset of the employee data than `PATCH` it. Note further that by definition, a URI of the form `/employee/{empId}/skill` does not necessarily state a parent-child relationship as the whole URI itself targets one specific endpoint and is used as cache-key on retrieval attempts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What would be the best approach / practice when documenting REST API with this scenario?

It may be worth reviewing [Jim Webber's 2011 talk.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQVSzMV8DWc&t=3m8s); in short, if you are doing REST, then you are passing around documents -- the useful work performed on your domain model is a *side effect* of document manipulation.

If you are using `PUT`/`PATCH`, then you are fundamentally performing remote authoring -- which is to say, you are asking the server to accept your local copy of a document.  And that's *fine*, even when the server, in accepting your edits, will also be changing its  representation of other resources.

You could instead design your application domain protocol so that you are making remote edits to the employee document directly, or even `POST`-ing edits to that resource, which in turn could have side effects on a skill resource.

Remember, the first application designed using the REST architectural style was the World Wide Web; the most common media-type for defining domain application protocols was HTML, and the only unsafe request method natively supported by HTML was `POST` -- and this was catastrophically successful.

So `POST` is *fine*.

Where things tend to get tricky is when you are trying to support generic components that want to take advantage of [caching](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234).  Then, you need to be thinking about the rules for invalidating cached data when you design your protocol.